# Вставить переменные в string

Tags: ios, строки, swift, if, for

Есть файл со строками. Пример (@NAME, должен потанцевать с @NAME)
Я пытаюсь заменить все "@NAME" именами с массива.
Оно меняет на рандомное имя и получается так (Alex, должен потанцевать с Alex).

Подскажите как я должен доработать свой код. Что бы имена не повторялись в строке.Я знаю что должен быть цикл, но не могу написать правильный.

Есть следующий код.

```
 func getAction()
    {
        //Name
        let firstName = nameForGame.randomElement()
        var secondName = nameForGame.randomElement()
        while secondName == firstName
        {
            secondName = nameForGame.randomElement()
        }
        //content file
        let contentFile = readFile.init()
        contentFile.getDataFromFile(name: "Action", type: "txt")
        let contentFromFileAction = content
        //replace name
        var replaceName = contentFromFileAction?.replacingOccurrences(of: "@NAME1", with: firstName!, options: .literal, range: nil)
            replaceName  = contentFromFileAction?.replacingOccurrences(of: "@NAME2", with: secondName!, options: .literal, range: nil)

        actionLabel.text = replaceName!
    }
```

Comment: Нужно использовать уникальные плейсхолдеры. Или явно указывать, что только один должен заменяться.

Comment: @Akina Я думал за плейсхолдеры, но не совсем понял как они работают. Моли бы Вы, привести какой то пример ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы имена не повторялись, можно сделать так

```
let names = ["Alex", "Ann", "Andrew", "Sonya", "Kate"]

func findName(with name: String) -> String {
    var secondName = name

    while secondName == name {
        secondName = names.randomElement() ?? ""
    }

    return secondName;
}

// ...

let firstName = findName(with: "")

let secondName = findName(with: firstName)
```

После этого подставляем полученные имена в вашу строку, проще будет, если вы сделаете `@NAME_1, должен потанцевать с @NAME_2`

Либо, если плейсхолдер одинаковый, можно сначала заменить первый, потом второй

```
let placeholderString = "@NAME"
var targetString = "\(placeholderString), должен потанцевать с \(placeholderString)"

var placeholderRange = targetString.range(of: placeholderString)
targetString = targetString.replacingOccurrences(of: placeholderString, with: firstName, options: .caseInsensitive, range: placeholderRange)

// ...

placeholderRange = targetString.range(of: placeholderString)
targetString = targetString.replacingOccurrences(of: placeholderString, with: secondName, options: .caseInsensitive, range: placeholderRange)
```

Comment: Для этой строки метод подходит. А у меня этих строк много и имена в разных местах. Как мне подставлять , если имя в середине например и пока строку не достают с файла, неизвестно где будет имя .

Comment: @MastIos проще всего сделать для разных имен разные плейсхолдеры или заменять имена по порядку их следования в строке, как предложено выше, если имен больше двух, то замену можно производить в цикле

Comment: Я отредактировал свой код в вопросе. Я установил "@NAME1" i "@NAME2"
и для каждого меня отдельно, но при выводе на label у меня меняется только второе имя , а первое остаётся "@NAME1"

Comment: @MastIos попробуйте так: `replaceName  = replaceName.replacingOccurrences(of: "@NAME2", with: secondName!, options: .literal, range: nil)`

Comment: Да! То что мне нужно) Больше спасибо вам за помощь!!

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант:

```
let nameOne = "Имя1"
let nameTwo = "Имя2"
label.text = String(format: "%@, должен потанцевать с %@", nameOne, nameTwo)
```

Comment: Это не очень подходит. Тут код для конкретного стринга. А у меня их 500+(я беру из с фала) и имена не только вначале или в конце, могут быть где угодно.